# Unable to Commit Changes to Github Pages

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, terminal, github-pages

I have my portfolio deployed to my account on a.github.io.

I made some changes but they're not going live on the website. In fact, even though I make changes on visual studio, the commit section does not show any commits.

If i commit changes, I get

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
modified: node_modules/gh-pages/.cache/github.com!a!a.github.io.git (new commits)

no changes added to commit
```

even though I am making changes.

### So my changes aren't going live.

Edit:

Now, the commit worked but I get this when I push changes:

```
 ! [rejected]          master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/a/a.github.io.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: Nope, still not. Even if forced push my files, the commits were shown on GitHub but the website wasn't updated @VonC

Answer (score 0):

If you have made any changes, a git status should show them, and you should have done at some point a git add + git commit.

If the push still fails, check if your git status shows you a branch.

---

If not, you are in **[detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)** mode, which would explain why a commit is not pushed.

```
git switch -c tmp
git switch -C master tmp
```

That would then reset master to that current (detached HEAD) commit.

---

If you get:

```
new file...
```

At minimum you would need to do a `git add`+`git commit`, but again, double check the current branch.

Comment: If I do git status, I get ``new file:   src/assests/font-awesome/svgs/solid/archway.svg``` for literally everything

Comment: It says ```git: 'switch' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.```

Comment: I haven't used git a lot in the past. Could you please explain me as a beginner?

Comment: @x89 git switch is Git 2.23+: can you update easily? On which OS are you?

Comment: @x89 First, what does `git status` return?

Comment: git status returns ```new file:   src/logo.svg
        new file:   src/portfolio.js
        new file:   src/serviceWorker.js
        new file:   z<
``` for all files

Comment: I'm using Linux-Ubuntu

Comment: @x89 Does git status display first "`On branch xxx`"? And what does `git version` return?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208810/discussion-between-vonc-and-x89).